# File System with Real-Time Data Deduplication

Tags: filesystems, versioning, deduplication, files

Is there a file system that stores files under a hash so there are no duplicates? It can be under any operating system. I know Git does that, but I'm looking for something that can run in real-time.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Having many duplicate files, and trying to avoid deleting them or creating links to them. I think a FS should be able to save a hash and the number of links pointing to it...

Comment: Do you mean "inline" deduplication instead of a post-processing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ZFS does this, but it is not a file-level deduplication. It's two better: block level deduplication (the intermediary between block and file deduplication being byte deduplication).

On Linux, there is SDFS; however ZFS has some better features like the ability to use a solid state drive as a hash table store so you're not eating up enormous amounts of RAM for your hash table. ZFS calls this [L2ARC](https://blogs.oracle.com/brendan/entry/test).

As of the writing of this post, please do not use ZFS on Linux. It needs to stay in the oven for a few more years. Use a BSD for ZFS.

Comment: SDFS is hosted [here](http://opendedup.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. ZFS does this, though it might 'bend' your definition of 'real-time'.